# Java Script sequential execution of function

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am not able to understand grasp the process of sequentially running functions in JavaScript. I read many posts on this topic on stackoverflow, but they did not enlight me.
Let us assume that we have two function fastFunction() and slowFunction(). When I run them one after the other JavaScript will not run them sequentially.

```
function fastFunction() {
    console.log('fast function!');
}

function slowFunction() {
    setTimeout(() => {console.log('slowFunction!')}, 1000);
}

slowFunction();
fastFunction();
```

I tried to use callbacks, promises and async/await syntax (see next example), but I am not able to get JavaScript to run these functions in sequential order. To be quite honest I still wonder why such a fundamental problem is that difficult to solve in JavaScript :D!

```
function fastFunction() {
    console.log('fast function!');
}

async function slowFunction() {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {console.log('slowFunction!')}, 1000)});
    let result = await promise;
}

slowFunction().then(fastFunction())
```

I would be glad if anyone could explain me what I am doing wrong.

**Edit**: After suggestion of passing fastFunction() as callback (not sure if that is what the comment was suggesting), does not solve the problem.

```
function fastFunction() {
    console.log('fast function!');
}

function slowFunction(callback) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('slowFunction!');
        callback();
        }, 10000);
}

slowFunction(fastFunction);
```

Comment: Your `fastFunction()` is invoking `fastFunction` immediately. Pass it as a callback instead `slowFunction().then(fastFunction)`

Comment: @CertainPerformance As far as I understood callbacks are the old way to solve this problem (I was not able to resolve this problem with callbacks ...) and async / await is the new way of solving this fundamental problem. I am so frustrated that I would also accept the callback solution. Could you tell me what I would need to modify in order to get the desired solution?

Comment: Well, `.then` accepts a callback. It's Promise-based, which is better, but it still uses a callback. There's no way around that. Do what I said in the first comment and it'll work as desired

Comment: @CertainPerformance I am not sure how to modify the code to get what you said. I edited the code but it still fails to do what I want. Could you edit my last code section such that it works?

Comment: Your new code is both omitting the Promise and it's *still* invoking `fastFunction` immediately. Just *pass* `fastFunction` as an argument - don't call it. See the code in my first comment

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thank you for you patience (this is the first time I work with JavaScript). If I change the last line to slowFunction(fastFunction) the fastFunction is not executed at all.

Comment: Oh, you're creating a Promise, but you're never resolving it; the `promise` variable remains an unresolved Promise forever. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises - in order to promisify `setTimeout`, you need to call `resolve` inside `setTimeout`'s callback: `setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('slowFunction!')
      resolve();
    }, 1000)`

Comment: @CertainPerformance Finally, I have a working solution! Thank you alot for your patience. I still think JavaScript should have a simpler solution to this problem without this complicated callback pattern.